# We can rollback without saying "Rollback"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions

I am doing this in SQL Server 2005.
I have a table, there is only one column of type int, o you cannot insert char in it.

If I run this, I will have one row inserted into my table.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(3)   --success 
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('b') --fail, cannot insert char
```

If I run this, I will have ZERO row inserted into my table. So a transactions group 2 tasks into a single execution unit. If one task fail, the whole transaction fail.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('b')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

My question is: It seem like ROLLBACK TRANSACTION is useless because I don't have ROLLBACK in the above code but it is still rolled back.... Could anybody help me to understand this?

Comment: If *none* of your statements fail, but you nonetheless want to revoke the changes, `ROLLBACK` is very useful. :)

Comment: is that ALL your code? (or at least the all *relevant* code)

Comment: @ MilkyWayJoe: yes, this is all my code. Just for learning.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, all code runs in an implicit transaction by default.  If you're submitting both statements in one batch and you have the query option XACT_ABORT on, any failure should roll back the entire transaction.  The default behavior is to only rollback the statement that caused the error.  If you submit the statements in their own batches (either by highlighting them individually in SSMS and hitting F5 or putting "go" statements between), I think you'll see different behavior.